# 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'serialize'

Tags: python, linux, docker, sqlite

i would like to use serialize/deserialize methods of sqlite in linux.
So i need python 3.11 and sqlite >= 3.39
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

I then took a docker image of python 3.11.4 and compiled the latest version of sqlite, then replaced the library.

```
RUN cd /opt/sqlite && tar -zxf sqlite-autoconf-3430000.tar.gz && cd /opt/sqlite/sqlite-autoconf-3430000 && \
    CFLAGS="-Os -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_DESERIALIZE=1 -DSQLITE_MEMDB_DEFAULT_MAXSIZE=17179869184 -DSQLITE_MAX_MEMORY=17179869184 -DSQLITE_MAX_ALLOCATION_SIZE=2147483391 " ./configure  && \
    make install && LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./configure --enable-optimizations
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Sqlite works correctly but if i run:

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.version) -> 2.6.0
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version) -> 3.43.0
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.serialize()
```

I get the error

```
'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

It looks like the db-api interface hasn't updated. Someone can help me?

Comment: Why you need to compile sqlite ? Can you use the default sqlite version ?

Comment: I need a sqlite version with serialize/deserialize api. Sqlite default version in this docker image is 3.34 (debian bullseye). And I need to use this image.